# DownloadDataTaskAsync & JsonConvert.DeserializeObject. will raise the following error :- can not convert cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, json.net

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC5 web application + EF6.0. I have the following async action method.

```
public ActionResult ScanServer(string tokenfromt, string FQDN)
{
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        string url = currentURL + "resources/" + passwordmanagerResourceID +
                     "/accounts/" + passwordmanagerAccountID + 
                     "/password?AUTHTOKEN=" + pmtoken;

        var json = await wc.DownloadDataTaskAsync(url);
        resourceAccountPasswordListInfo =
            JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountPasswordInfo>(json);
    }
}

public class ResourcesInfo
{
    public Operation operation { get; set; }
}
```

But this is raising the following exceptions.

> Error 1   The best overloaded method match for 'Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(string)'
>   has some invalid arguments    C:\Users.....\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tScanningFinal\tScanningFinal\Controllers\HomeController.cs 155 63  tScanningFinal
>
> Error 2   Argument 1: cannot convert from 'byte[]' to 'string'    C:\Users\M......\Visual Studio
>   2012\Projects\tScanningFinal\tScanningFinal\Controllers\HomeController.cs 155 122 tScanningFinal

Comment: And what are you trying to deserialize?

Comment: @beautifulcoder i am trying to deserialize a josn object to a model class . here is the model class :-  public class ResourcesInfo
    {
        public Operation operation { get; set; }
    }

Comment: [`WebClient.DownloadDataTaskAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/Hh138334%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) returns a byte array.  Maybe you want [`WebClient.DownloadStringAsync`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144202%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @dbc noted, this is a typing issue. `DeserializeObject<T>(string value)` takes in a string parameter not a byte array: [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject Method (String)](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_DeserializeObject__1.htm).

You have two alternatives, either:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResourceAccountPasswordInfo>(json.ToString());
```

OR

```
var json = await wc.DownloadStringAsync(url);
```

Also, make sure the json is legit through the debugging tooling.